# Failed to Send Contact Information to the mail id

Tags: php, email, form-submit, contact-form

I developed this code for sending a contact information after filling out the contact form. But still, it is not working anymore. It is showing continuously message "Not Ok". I am not able to find out the error. please guide me to make this code workable.

Sorry, I haven't added any php code-
please check it below now updated One.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['fname'])&& !empty($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){
            $fname = $_POST['fname'];
            $lname = $_POST['lname'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

                echo 'Kindly proivde valid email id';
            }else{
                    $body = $fname."\n".$lname."\n".$email."\n".$message;
                    if(mail('example@mail.com','Website Response',$body,'From: response@self.com')){
                        echo 'Thanks for contacting us.';
                    } else {
                        echo "Error Occured in sending mail";
                    }
            }

        } else{
            echo 'All fields are mandatory';
        }
    } else{
            echo 'Not ok';
    }


    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-top: 6px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        resize: vertical;
    }

    input[type=submit] {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=submit]:hover {
        background-color: #45a049;
    }

    .container {
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h3>Contact Form</h3>

    <div class="container">
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="emailid" placeholder="example@company.com">
        </br>
        <label for="message">Description</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="subject" rows="6" cols="30" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit Details">
      </form>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is you **PHP** Code which is used to send email.?

Comment: same question there is something wrong with your php code not html share your php code.

Comment: you need some php code to fetch submitted data and send it in mail.

Comment: Yes, updated here. Please go through it.

Comment: You access form values through the name` attribute` not the `id` attribute

Comment: Thanks, Then @JohnConde, what I need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You need change:

```
<form action="your_name.php" method="POST">
```

And create file "your_name.php", where you can Post all parameters from your form.
For example:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$emailid = $_POST['emailid'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
```

And if you want to send information to checked e-mail, you must use function mail()
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php